# PHP - Timestamp Conversion Issue

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert a timestamp that's stored in a database from the `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS` format to `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS` format but I'm getting an error

> "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on a non-object"

**Here's my code:**

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
 $clientTimestamp = '10/25/2015 21:22:47';
 $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y h:i:s", $clientTimestamp );
 $clientTimestampAU = $date->format("d/m/Y h:i:s");
```

I'm getting the error on the last line - I can't work out what the issue is here.

Comment: `m/d/Y H:i:s` and `d/m/Y H:i:s`.... upper-case `H` for 24-hr clock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hour parameter is `H` and not `h`

So, instead of

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
$clientTimestamp = '10/25/2015 21:22:47';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y h:i:s", $clientTimestamp );
$clientTimestampAU = $date->format("d/m/Y h:i:s");
```

Make it

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
$clientTimestamp = '10/25/2015 21:22:47';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y H:i:s", $clientTimestamp );
$clientTimestampAU = $date->format("d/m/Y H:i:s");
```